# Open a Dialogue box after click on a promoted link

Tags: dialog

My goal is to open a promoted link in a dialog box. When I create the promoted link i click on launch in dialog box, however, it keeps on coming back with the message something went wrong. How do I get the content in the promoted link to open in a Dialog box.

If you can step by step instructions would be great.

Comment: Generally there is no error on enable dialog in prompted link. Please see the log filtered with correlation id to get actual error.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've noticed:

1. My promoted links:
   [image]
2. First link points to a list item
3. Second link points to an external site
4. Only link pointing to a SharePoint resource is displaying in a dialog:
   [image]
5. Links outside domain will not work until these sites are configured to be able to display in iFrame. The external link will result with an error message inside the dialog.